# ternary operator in jenkins environment variable

Tags: jenkins

I need to give a ternary operation in one of the "Environment" variable in Jenkins. Is it possible? E.g. `Sample_Variable`

```
pipeline {
    parameters {
        booleanParam (defaultValue: false,
            description: 'Check this if you want to do allow comments?',
            name: 'ALLOW_COMMENTS')

        string(name: 'ENTER_COMMENTS', defaultValue: '', description: 'Allow comments for this example..') 
    }

    environment {
        Sample_Variable: "${params.ALLOW_COMMENTS == true ? params.ENTER_COMMENTS:env.SOME_OTHER_ENV_VARIABLE}"
    }
}
```

I searched the internet but didn't get anything. I tried something like above but it throws error:

```
Obtained Jenkinsfile from d1b56c1a276aa09424c88f25e052359f35f1a64c
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
General error during class generation: Method code too large!

java.lang.RuntimeException: Method code too large!
    at groovyjarjarasm.asm.MethodWriter.a(Unknown Source)
    at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassWriter.toByteArray(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$17.call(CompilationUnit.java:827)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1065)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:603)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:131)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:125)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:560)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:521)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:325)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
environment {
    Sample_Variable: (params.ALLOW_COMMENTS) ? "${params.ENTER_COMMENTS}" : "${env.SOME_OTHER_ENV_VARIABLE}"
}
```